# How to programmatically set RGB color for TextColor property of a Label in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a solution for programmatically set RGB color for text of a label in Xamarin.forms. What I want is to passing RGB code like "#f56400" to TextColor property of a label instead of passing Color.Green like bellow:

```
        searchOnclickListener.Tapped += (s, e) =>
        {
            btn_search_lbl.TextColor = Color.Green;
        };
        search_parent.GestureRecognizers.Add(searchOnclickListener);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Color.FromRGB(#f56400)
Something like that

Comment: Why don't just make this as an answer? this is exactly what I need, thanks a lot.

Comment: Cant, as it was marked as duplicate. But you can up-vote my comment :)